# Condition for the number of distinct solutions over GF($q$)

Tags: combinatorics, finite-groups, field-theory, finite-fields

Assume that we have $p$ sets $\left\{ {{m_i}} \right\}_{i = 1}^p$ with given cardinalities $\left\{ {{K_i}} \right\}_{i = 1}^p$, $1 \le {K_i} \le q$, where $q$ is a power of $2$. What I'm trying to do is to find a condition for the content of the sets, such that the sums (using GF($q$) arithmetic) of combinations of elements from the sets gives $n=1,2,...,q$ unique elements of GF($q$).

For example, assume that we have $2$ sets, both with cardinality $2$:

$${m_1} = \left\{ {{x_1},{x_2}} \right\},{m_2} = \left\{ {{x_3},{x_4}} \right\}$$

with $x_i$ taken from GF($q$). We have the following sums:

$${x_1} + {x_3},{x_1} + {x_4},{x_2} + {x_3},{x_2} + {x_4}$$

(in general we have $\prod\limits_{i = 1}^p {{K_i}} $ such sums). Is there a condition that guarantees that the number of distinct sums equals $n=1,2,...,q$? (it is clear that we have at least ${\max _i}{K_i}$ distinct sums). An approximate condition would also be helpful.

(this question is similar to one posted at csthoery, but now with focusing on the mathematical structure of GF($q$).

Edit:

- If it helps, it can be assumed that $0 \in m_i$ for all $i$.
- In the meantime, I noted that if $m_i$ are **subgroups** of the group formed by the elements of gf($q$) (with '+') ($K_i$ therefore must be a divisor of $q$), then for each pair $m_i,m_j$ we have:

$$\left| {{m_i}+{m_j}} \right| = \frac{{\left| {{m_i}} \right|\left| {{m_j}} \right|}}{{\left| {{m_i} \cap {m_j}} \right|}}$$

where:

$${m_i} + {m_j} = \left\{ {a + b:a \in {m_i},b \in {m_j}} \right\}$$

I should also add that given sets $\left\{ {{m_i}} \right\}_{i = 1}^p$ (with elements taken from gf($q$)) with given cardinalities $K_i$, I'm able to calculate the probability that the size of their intersection equals $n=1,2,...,q$.

Comment: This sounds like a question that might well be answerable if translated into _coding theory_ terms. Each set $m_i$ is a _code_, a collection of binary vectors of length $N = \log_2 q$, and you are asking about sums of codewords, one from each code.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: I assume that you refer (in general) to non-linear codes (in each set). I thought indeed on representing elements of GF($q=2^l$) by binary vectors of length $l$, where the addition is performed bit-wise. However, I don't see how it simplifies the question - can you please elaborate?

Comment: The reason that I think it simplifies the question is that you really are not using any properties of the **field** $GF(2^k)$ that are not properties of the **vector space** $[GF(2)]^k$, that is, _multiplication_ of field elements is not an issue at all. But, if you want to insist that the field is relevant and coding theory has nothing to say about the matter, that's fine by me.

Comment: You are right that I have not taken yet the multiplication of the field elements into account. I of course don't insist that coding theory is irrelevant, I just don't see how - I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: A bit difficult to say much right away. Of course, by selecting $m_i=\{0,x_i\},i=1,2,\ldots,p,$ we get the subspace spanned by $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_p$, but that is probably an easy, uninteresting case. This generalizes a bit in the sense that if $K_i=2$ for all $i$, we get a coset of the subspace spanned by the sum vectors of all the sets (=pairs).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: In fact I can assume (for the particular case I'm trying to solve) that $0 \in m_i$ for all $i$, if it simplifies the problem. However, I can't assume $K_i=2$.

Comment: Understood. A point was that if we subtract a vector from all the elements of the set $m_i$, we subtract the same vector from all the sums. So for the purposes of counting the number of distinct sums it does not change anything to assume that $0\in m_i$ for all $i$. I'm afraid that was the easy part :-)